# Resizing objects from Cartesian measurements to Ellipsoidal

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, scale, ellipsoid, cartesian

I have been working on a project in QGIS 3.12.2 in EPSG 3857 so it works with google earth. Without realising the difference there would be between cartesian and ellipsoidal I buffered some points.

By default Q does this using a Cartesian system. The rest of my map is brought straight into QGIS but measurements are ellipsoidal. This means my buffer that I specified to 2km actually is about 1.5km in respect to the rest of the map. Not realising this at first I proceeded to do a few days worth of work mapping paths within the 2k buffers which now I've realised are all too small in relation to the rest of the maps.

I was wondering if there is a way to rescale from cartesian to ellipsoidal measures so I can get everything back in line in one mass rescaling rather than having to redo everything.

Comment: As we don't know your whole workflow, your question is the broad/too vague. If you want to apply buffers considering earth's curvature, use geodesic buffers, see ehere how to do that in QGIS: https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/05/geodesic-buffers-in-qgis - if it is just to create buffers, you have to create them again with in ellipsoidal measurements and repeat the steps that are based on that.